# Getting 422:Unprocessable Entity when trying to add maven package form github registry to a gradle file

Tags: build.gradle, github-package-registry

I have a jar out in gitHub package registry called test.jar (version: 1.0.5), the repository name is testRepo, owner name: tejas3108.

I am trying to add this jar as a dependency in my other gradle project, but with correct credentials, I still get this message: `Could not GET 'https://maven.pkg.github.com/tejas3108/com.tejas/1.0.5/testRepo-1.0.5.pom'. Received status code 422 from server: Unprocessable Entity.`
Pasting the same in the browser gives the message: Invalid path for maven file.

How do I successfully add this jar from the github registry to my build.gradle? Here is what I have now:

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven{
        url = "https://maven.pkg.github.com/tejas3108"
        credentials {
            username = "tejas3108"
            password = "<my_github_token>"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
   compile "com.tejas:testRepo:1.0.5"
}
```

Answer (score 6):

The URL should include the repository name, as per the [documentation](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-packages-with-github-packages/configuring-gradle-for-use-with-github-packages#authenticating-to-github-packages). So, in your case, write:

```
url = "https://maven.pkg.github.com/tejas3108/testRepo"
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be also because the artifact group must be unique in your Github organisation / account.
So for example if you already have the same artifact in a different Github repository of your organisation or account

Answer (score 0):

My issue was an uppcase letter in `mArtifactId`

```
    publications {
        maven(MavenPublication) {
            groupId mGroupId
            artifactId mArtifactId
            version mVersionName
```